# What does an AWS Glue Crawler do

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I've read the AWS glue docs re: the crawlers here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html but I'm still on unclear on what exactly the Glue crawler *does*. Does a Crawler go through your S3 buckets, and create pointers to those buckets?

When the docs say "The output of the crawler consists of one or more metadata tables that are defined in your Data Catalog" what is the purpose of these metadata tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CRAWLER creates the metadata that allows GLUE and services such as ATHENA to view the S3 information as a database with tables. That is, it allows you to create the Glue Catalog.

This way you can see the information that s3 has as a database composed of several tables.

For example if you want to create a crawler you must specify the following fields:

Database --> Name of database
Service role    service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole
Selected classifiers --> Specify Classifier
Include path   --> S3 location

Answer (score 4):

Crawlers are needed to analyze data in specified s3 location and generate/update Glue Data Catalog which is basically is a meta-store for actual data (similar to [Hive metastore](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Design#Design-Metastore)). In other words it persists information about physical location of data, its schema, format and partitions which makes it possible to query actual data via Athena or to load it in Glue jobs.

I would suggest to read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-data-catalog.html) documentation to understand Glue crawlers better and of course make some experiments.

Comment: Can I ask you is there a way to set Glue to update the table with the latest S3 file?, I am running an appflow an each time it creates a new file, each time run the crawler to get th elatest informaiton it concatenate all the files, so I end up having duplictes because of this, just wondering how can I get the last file